# Imprimir arquivo do word pelo c#

Tags: c#, impressão, microsoft-word

Ola pessoal estou tentando imprimir um arquivo word.doc, estou usando o seguinte código.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        string CaminhoContrato ="C:\\arquvio.doc";
        Document document = application.Documents.Open(CaminhoContrato);
```

Dessa forma eu consigo abri-lo, mas preciso mesmo imprimir o arquivo sem que ele seja aberto. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou isso aqui?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
string caminhoContrato ="C:\\arquvio.doc";
Document document = application.Documents.Open(caminhoContrato);
document.Activate();
document.PrintOut();
```

Comment: Assim está dando erro na linha  application.Documents.Open(...)oMissing);

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes que erro?

Comment: ele não aceita o código

Comment: Deixa só o application.Documents.Open(CaminhoContrato); então

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes fiz umas mudanças ali

Answer (score 2):

Usei esse código.Não`using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`
Meu código ficou assim.

```
string CaminhoArquivo = "C:\\arquivo.doc";

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(CaminhoContrato);
            wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(true, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument,
Item: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies: "2", Pages: "1",
PageType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages, PrintToFile: false, Collate: true,
ManualDuplexPrint: false);
            doc.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            doc = null;
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApp).Quit(SaveChanges: false);
            wordApp = null;
```

Dessa forma ele não abre a caixa de dialogo da impressora.
Imprime diereto

Comment: Olá Amigo blza?
Você conseguiu imprimir mais de uma página dessa maneira que voce postou, Estou tentando aqui, mas só funciona quando tem uma pagina. Agradeço se puder dar uma dica.